# Font is not applied on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to convert an `SVG` to `PNG` using `d3.js` and `HTML5`. When the image is displayed, custom font is applied on it, but when I save image as png, font is not applied on that image.
below is my code

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Calligraffitti";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("Calligraffitti"), local("Calligraffitti-Regular"), url("http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/calligraffitti/v7/vLVN2Y-z65rVu1R7lWdvyKIZAuDcNtpCWuPSaIR0Ie8.woff") format("woff");
}
```

**JS**

```
 $('.savePNG').click(function() { saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("treeT"), "tree2.png", 3);
    out.saveSvgAsPng = function(el, name, scaleFactor) {
    out.svgAsDataUri(el, scaleFactor, function(uri) {

      var image = new Image();
      image.src = uri;

      image.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download = name;
        a.id        = "download_link";
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In which file did you put the CSS you posted?  If it is in your HTML, or referenced from your HTML file, then you are out of luck, because CSS does not apply across document boundaries.  So it would not affect a separate SVG file.

In theory you could put the CSS in the SVG file.  That would work except for the fact that you are loading the SVG as an `<img>` (Image()).  Due to security restrictions in the browser, SVGs loaded as an `<img>` **must be self-contained**.  They cannot reference external objects (such as font files).

The solution would be to embed the CSS in your SVG file *and* use a dataURI to reference the font.

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Calligraffitti";
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local("Calligraffitti"), local("Calligraffitti-Regular"), url("data:application/font-woff;base64,...font.file.encoded.as.base64...") format("woff");
    }
  ]]></style>
</defs>
```

I believe this should work.

Comment: In reality, I don't have any SVG file, Just using the function to convert the text area into png

Comment: Not working for me either.
Perhaps it only works if the font isn't from a URL but as a base64 inline string?